# Why does lodash run test suites of backbone.js and underscore.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, lodash

I am new to lodash and currently learning it. One question came up when I looked at the Github repository of it. In the Github respository, the test directory includes test suites of backbone.js and underscore.js ([Link](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/tree/master/test)). I am curious why lodash run test suites of other JavaScript libraries.

Comment: It started as a fork of underscore. The tests are probably to ensure that it can be swapped with underscore in an existing project without breaking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [lodash wiki](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Migrating#backbone):

> Lodash works great with Backbone. It’s even run against Backone’s unit
>   tests on every commit. You can replace Underscore with Lodash in
>   Backbone by using an [AMD loader](http://requirejs.org/), [browserify](http://browserify.org/), or [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/).
>
> **Note**: Lodash v4 works with Backbone ≥ v1.3.0.

Comment: Yep, Lodash is run against the unit tests of Underscore and Backbone to ensure compatibility.